# why auto.arima() and Arima() are different?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I fitted model by function `auto.arima()`, then i tried to fit again by function `Arima()` with same model, but i got different results.

By `auto.arima()`:

```
> a<-c(90,88,96,110,105,128,119,117,155,135,138,127,156,168,145,160,180,175,189,166,184)
> chuoi<-ts(a,frequency=1,start=c(1990))
> auto.arima(chuoi)
Series: chuoi 
ARIMA(2,1,0) with drift         

Coefficients:
          ar1      ar2   drift
      -0.7075  -0.4648  4.7897
s.e.   0.1930   0.1972  1.3689

sigma^2 estimated as 163.1:  log likelihood=-79.7
AIC=167.39   AICc=170.06   BIC=171.38
```

By `Arima()` with same model, used all method "CSS-ML","ML" and "CSS":

```
> fit210<-Arima(chuoi,c(2,1,0),method="ML")
> fit210
Series: chuoi 
ARIMA(2,1,0)                    

Coefficients:
          ar1      ar2
      -0.4670  -0.1928
s.e.   0.2162   0.2201

sigma^2 estimated as 244.2:  log likelihood=-83.48
AIC=172.96   AICc=174.46   BIC=175.95
> fit210<-Arima(chuoi,c(2,1,0),method="CSS")
> fit210
Series: chuoi 
ARIMA(2,1,0)                    

Coefficients:
          ar1      ar2
      -0.4876  -0.2111
s.e.   0.2196   0.2304

sigma^2 estimated as 268.3:  part log likelihood=-84.3
> fit210<-Arima(chuoi,c(2,1,0),method="CSS-ML")
> fit210
Series: chuoi 
ARIMA(2,1,0)                    

Coefficients:
          ar1      ar2
      -0.4671  -0.1928
s.e.   0.2162   0.2201

sigma^2 estimated as 244.2:  log likelihood=-83.48
AIC=172.96   AICc=174.46   BIC=175.95
```

Obviously I got different coefficients ar(1), ar(2). Then, how function `auto.arima()` calculated coefficients ar(1), ar(2)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first model includes drift, you need to run it with

```
Arima(chuoi,c(2,1,0),include.drift = TRUE)
```

These two are the same:

```
auto.arima(chuoi) 
Arima(chuoi,c(2,1,0),include.drift = TRUE) # default model, but with drift
```

Output:

```
> auto.arima(chuoi)
Series: chuoi 
ARIMA(2,1,0) with drift         

Coefficients:
          ar1      ar2   drift
      -0.7075  -0.4648  4.7897
s.e.   0.1930   0.1972  1.3689

sigma^2 estimated as 163.1:  log likelihood=-79.7
AIC=167.39   AICc=170.06   BIC=171.38



>   Arima(chuoi,c(2,1,0),include.drift = T)
Series: chuoi 
ARIMA(2,1,0) with drift         

Coefficients:
          ar1      ar2   drift
      -0.7075  -0.4648  4.7897
s.e.   0.1930   0.1972  1.3689

sigma^2 estimated as 163.1:  log likelihood=-79.7
AIC=167.39   AICc=170.06   BIC=171.38
>
```

Comment: Thanks very much @rbm. I tried and got true result. I need read more about Arima().

Comment: @Duong Dinh Tu  If you are happy with the answer, you should consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: The adjusted `d` value in arma order will made the model more accurate. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26926/fitting-arima-with-a-drift-on-r